# Python: Execute console_script on windows

Tags: python, windows

I wrote a small command line tool. A http upload client called [tbzuploader](https://github.com/guettli/tbzuploader)

I use Python on linux daily, but I have no clue how to use a `console_script` (via setup.py) on windows.

Where does pip install my command line tool?

Background: the tool should be executed regularly via the windows task scheduler

Comment: It'll be in the "Scripts" folder of the target interpreter. The task scheduler should run the tool using its fully-qualified path.

Comment: @eryksun If you write your comment as answer, I will up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts get installed in this directory:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```